# unable to set background image properly in getView method

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, android-button

Following shows the code and screenshot for displaying data in `listview` containing 3 `textview`.

I tried the following code in `getView()` method of `Adapter` class to give background image to alternate rows i.e. row no. 0,2,4,etc.

When I try to implement this, I get the output as shown in screen-shots i.e. row are not getting effected appropriately.

Also, refer to below `xml` in which `alignTop` and `alignBottom` parameters are used, still on `Index` button click, 2nd and 3rd `textview` are not getting background color appropriately.

**EDIT - If I use colour instead of image for background, it works well for all cases except for `Index` button.**

```
if (count % 2 == 0) {

    try {

        InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open("cellbg.png");
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "cellbg");
        holder.txtFirst.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        holder.txtSecond.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        holder.txtThird.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        Log.v("count=", "" + (count++));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error(" exception in TableListAdapter " + e.getMessage());
    }
} else {
    Log.v("else count==", "" + (count++));
}
```

**list structure(xml)**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/FirstText"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SecondText"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/FirstText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/FirstText"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ThirdText"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/FirstText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/FirstText"/>
```

1st screen shows the list structure at the time of application launch, where by default, `Gainers` button is pressed.

2nd shows an instance of pressing `Index` button.

3rd shows an instance of pressing `Gainers` button again after pressing index button.

4th shows the layout when `List item` is clicked.

*What am I doing wrong?*

**ANY HELP WILL BE LIFE-SAVER !!!**

[image: screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things.... not sure what the different buttons are and what they do, but it should not matter...

You should set the background also when `(count % 2 != 0)` because the views can be reused in the list, so better be safe.

Also, instead of setting the background for the different `TextViews` individually, why not set it only for the `ViewGroup` that contains all those `TextViews` (I imagine a `LinearLayout` or something like that) ?

Just to double check, `count` is the argument you get when `getView` gets called ?
Maybe you could post a bit more code of your `getView` method, that would probably help (to get a better answer).

Comment: THANKS A TON BUDDY... Just added `holder.l1.setBackgroundDrawable(d);` in place of setting background to each textView and it worked.

But I didn't got why I should set the background when (count % 2 != 0) because in this case Table bg  will be automatically used.

Comment: It all depends on your getView method... to make it faster you should reuse views (that's the convertView argument), in that case, you should set the background all the time since you don't know what you are getting.

Comment: but what if I want to assign different background image to each textbox?

Comment: I've declared textview like this `holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.FirstText);`....

Comment: If everything works, don't worry about it, but if you see some rows have the background set when they are not supposed to, then that will be your problem...

Answer (score 1):

This looks the a view reuse problem to be but I can't be sure because I don't see that part of the code. In your `getView` do you reuse views (i.e. do you make use of `convertView` parameter)? If you do, then that's your answer. You have to always set the background to the color you want. Something like this:

```
if (count % 2 == 0) {
    ...
    holder.txtFirst.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
} else {
    holder.txtFirst.setBackgroundDrawable(myDefaultRowColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using setbackgrounddrawable but i think you have to use below code to set image

```
holder.txtFirst.setImageResource(R.drawable.Imagename);
```